# How to minimize typing when frequently changing directories?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, tab-completion, cd

What are some good Linux commands to make switching between different directories on the command line easier?

I often have to switch between different directories with long names, e.g.

```
cd foo/20100801-rev124-test2
ls 
cd ../20100801-rev124-test1
ls 
cd ../20100802-rev126-bar
```

Typically, I use tab completion, so it's something like this:

```
cd ../2010080Tab2Tab-rev12Tab6-Tabbar
```

But it's annoying because all these names are so similar, so tab completion doesn't really save much work.

What tricks do you use to minimize typing in such situations?

BTW, I do use `pushd` and `popd` sometimes, but here it won't help much because I don't visit the directories in a given order.

**UPDATE:**

For a nice solution, see the [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/questions/171999/smart-tab-completion-for-directories/172005#172005) to my other, [related question](https://superuser.com/questions/171999/smart-tab-completion-for-directories/). Basically, just create an alternative `cd` command:

```
function cd2 { select a in $1*; do cd $a; break; done }
```

It will list all possible completions at once:

```
$ cd2 2010080
(1) 20100801-rev124-test2
(2) 20100801-rev124-test1
(3) 20100802-rev126-bar
```

and you can pick one by typing its number.

Comment: Hmm, unless the solution requires coming up with a bash script or similar.

Comment: use a good file manager with bookmarks and terminal integration. Also alias ".." to go to parent dir so you don't have to type "cd ..". And create symlinks to save typing.

Comment: @neoneye: A file manager with bookmarks and terminal integration would be nice. I can't find any; do you have a link?

Comment: I use mac.. however some file managers that is available for linux that most likely can do it: Dolphin, Worker. For textmode there is Midnight Commander.

Comment: `alias rotd='pushd -0'` then use `rotd` to rotate directory stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `dirs -v` command will list the directory stack with numbers in front of each directory, and you can give a number argument to the `pushd` command to have it jump to that directory. For example, if `dirs -v` shows that the directory you wish to change to has `2` in front of it (i.e., is the third directory in the list), executing `pushd +2` will change to that directory.

To save typing, you can shorten those commands by giving them aliases like this:

```
alias dv="dirs -v"
alias pd=pushd
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use wildcards:

```
cd ../*test1 or even cd *t1
cd ../2010*test2
cd ../*bar
```

They are much more flexibles and you don't need to plan a script for each different situation, once you are used to them, you will use them for all kind of directories.
Examples:

```
cd /e*/n*k will take you to /etc/network
cd /h* to /home
```

They are usable anywhere (`ls` also of course so you can filter what to see)

[bash wildcards](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/wildcards.html)

Comment: This may or may not be useful, depending on how many file patterns the glob matches.  if you have `/hard_disk` then `cd /h*` is less useful.

Comment: sure but if you use these commands a lot, you quickly find what is the match and it is almost always shorter than the full typing and you can use the others wildcards in the link. In your example, would be `cd /ho*` and yes... I agree this one isn't the best! :) but this is much more an exception and not the case of the OP as his directories names are long

Answer (score 1):

1. Try using the hist command to bring up the history of all commands you have executed.
2. Create a shell script with the cd commands for each directories that you often cd to.

Answer (score 1):

- Tab completion
- History access (especially in those shells that provide arrow key access)
- In bash, consider using `popd` and `pushd`

Comment: Thanks! What shells provide arrow key access?

Comment: Bash, tcsh. Maybe zsh. Probably some other. Start by just trying it. If that doesn't work, check the documentation. Search for "history" and possibly for "readline".

Comment: Oh, you mean accessing previous commands by arrow key. Okay, I'm using that in bash. I thought you meant accessing one of the tab completion candidates using the arrow keys.

Comment: New enough bashes also supports other readline features such as `C-r` for incremental history searching. As every shell is different the documentation is your friend.

Comment: I've been using bash for years and only just discovered `C-r` in the past few months. It's a wonderful thing.

Answer (score 1):

In a question like this, i'd say to mention which shell you use.  Each shell has slightly different tools.  My answers here apply to bash, which is what you're *probably* using.

Also, to 'Frank Computer', you can't use a shell script, it creates it's own process, cd's in that process, exits, and your current shell is still where you are.

I think 'alias' is your friend.  add something like:

```
alias CD_test2-'cd /absolute/path/to/foo/20100801-rev124-test2'
```

to your .bashrc (or .kshrc, or zshrc)

bash also has the env var `CDPATH`, which can be used as an anchor for cd'ing into relative paths.  For example:

```
CDPATH=/usr:.; cd bin
```

would see that there is a `/usr/bin` and put you there, then if not, put you in `./bin`.  This probably won't help you, because you'd probably have to type out the entire subdir for this to work :

```
CDPATH=/root/to/all/testing/dirs:.; cd 20100801-rev124-test2
```

Methinks alias is the best you can get, at least in bash.  There may be better tools in zsh.

Comment: I don't think scripts are the best way here but you can use a script to change directory if you source it calling it with `. my_cd_script` and put the `cd` command in the script.

Answer (score 1):

[Midnight Commander](http://www.midnight-commander.org) (`mc`) is a terminal-based (character mode) file manager. It has a hot-list feature that allows you to add directories to a list of those that you frequently use and select them from the list to cd to. It also has a quick cd feature that allows you to type in a full directory to cd into even while you're typing a command at the `mc` command line. You can also do the usual file manager navigation.

Another keystroke saver is to use the shell's `CDPATH` variable (it's available in most shells).

```
CDPATH=/some/top/dir:/another/one
cd foo
```

If "foo" exists in the current directory, then `cd` will move you there. If not, it will search the directories in `CDPATH` and move you to the first "foo" it finds there.

Answer (score 0):

[quickcd](https://github.com/jchain/quickcd) is a nice script to change directory quickly by saving a lot of typing.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://pypi.org/project/fastcd/
Seems to be more useful than aliases

Answer (score 0):

anc was designed exactly for that use case.

https://github.com/tobimensch/anc

Here's an excerpt from the README.md:

Examples:
    # make the current directory the default anchor:
    $ anc s

```
# go to /etc, then /, then /usr/local and then back to the default anchor:
$ cd /etc; cd ..; cd usr/local; anc

# go back to /usr/local :
$ anc b

# add another anchor:
$ anc a $HOME/test

# view the list of anchors (the default one has the asterisk):
$ anc l
(0) /path/to/first/anchor *
(1) /home/usr/test

# jump to the anchor we just added:
# by using its anchor number
$ anc 1
# or by jumping to the last anchor in the list
$ anc -1

# add multiple anchors:
$ anc a $HOME/projects/first $HOME/projects/second $HOME/documents/first

# use text matching to jump to $HOME/projects/first
$ anc pro fir

# use text matching to jump to $HOME/documents/first
$ anc doc fir

# add anchor and jump to it using an absolute path
$ anc /etc
# is the same as
$ anc a /etc; anc -1

# add anchor and jump to it using a relative path
$ anc ./X11 #note that "./" is required for relative paths
# is the same as
$ anc a X11; anc -1

# using wildcards you can add many anchors at once
$ anc a $HOME/projects/*

# use shell completion to see a list of matching anchors
# and select the one you want to jump to directly
$ anc pro[TAB]
```

Full disclosure: I'm the author of anc

Answer (score 0):

I've found that `cd -` greatly reduces typing, especially when a lot of the time is spent navigating back and forth between 2 directories. `cd -` changes to the previous directory.

Answer (score 0):

There are various shells and shell extensions that support [partial path autocomplete](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/94) and [fish](http://fishshell.com/) is one of them. For example `cd /v/l/fsck` <kbd>Tab</kbd> will convert the path to `/var/log/fsck/`. `cd /u/s/appl` <kbd>Tab</kbd> will expand the path to `/usr/share/applications/`

You can also use some [fuzzy search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching) software like

- [fuzzy bash completion](https://github.com/mgalgs/fuzzy_bash_completion)

  > This bash completion module performs "fuzzy" matching similar to textmate's "Go to File" fuzzy matching, "flex matching" in emacs' ido mode, etc.

  ```
    mkdir pizza
    mkdir jazz
    cd zz<TAB>
    # displays `pizza' and `jazz'
    rm -r jazz
    cd zz<TAB>
    # completes the word `pizza'
  ```
- [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf): *a general-purpose command-line fuzzy finder.* Just press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to cd into the selected directory

  Demo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qgG5Jhi_Els
- [Command-T](https://github.com/wincent/command-t):

  > Command-T is a Vim plug-in that provides an extremely fast "fuzzy" mechanism for:

  [image: Command-T in action]

See also

- [Find file modes in console (fuzzy completion)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5154539/995714)
- [Command-T for shell](https://superuser.com/q/392496/241386)