# Smart tab completion (for directories)?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tab-completion

Are there shell versions that have a more intelligent tab completion?

I'd like to be able to type

```
cd foo-<TAB>
```

Then it would show me the possible completions along with numbers that I can type to select one of them:

```
cd foo-<TAB>
(1) foo-bar1  (2) foo-bar2  (3) foo-bad
```

So, after `<TAB>` I would type `3` and it would take me to `foo-bad`. Alternatively, using the arrow keys instead of typing the number would be fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can enable `menu-complete` in Bash to step through the entries on the command line each time you press Tab. This is not really what you're looking for. If you want to try it, do this at the command prompt:

```
bind '"\C-i": menu-complete'
```

To make it persist, add this to your `~/.inputrc` file:

```
"\C-i": menu-complete
```

Zsh has a feature that allows you to use the arrow keys to select an entry. Add this (or another variation) to your `~/.zshrc` file:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select=0
```

See `man zshcompsys` and search for "select=" (it will be in the section for the `menu` "Standard Style") for more information.

Otherwise, in Bash, you could write a function (or even create your own completion function) that would do something based on the `select` command. This is extremely simplistic:

```
$ select a in x y z; do cd $a; done
1) x
2) y
3) z
#?
```

You'd have to flesh that out a lot to get it to do what you want.

Comment: I like your `select` solution. That's exactly what I wanted! I added a `break` after `cd $a`, and I'll alias this command. That's way better than tab completion.

Comment: @dehman: It's part of "flesh that out". You need a `break` statement. Try: `select a in x y z; do cd $a; break; done`. You can use `find` to build the list of directories to choose from rather than hardcoding them. Another thing you might want to look into is the [`CDPATH` variable](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC66) (and [here](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC59)).

Answer (score 9):

Do you already use normal completion?  try

```
complete -d cd pushd rmdir
```

In your shell and see if it is close enough to what you want.

You can also try zsh which has better completion than bash.

Comment: I was looking for a way to make autocomplete for cd exclude non-directories. This did it. You rock.

Comment: @Andy check out bash_completion @ http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/