# Quick jump to directory from shell

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell

Text editors like vim and emacs have plugins like ace jump, avy, that allow you to press a character, then it'll highlight every instance of that character with a temporary keybind, then you can press the keybind to jump directly to it

I wonder if something like that exists for shells (e.g. bash) to quickly navigate to a specific directory without having to `cd` through directories? Maybe something that will list directories to a certain depth, wait for an input character, highlight instances of character with a key sequence and `cd` into it when the sequence is pressed?

If something like that doesn't already exist, how easy would it be create?

Answer (score 2):

[`fzf`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) does that. It's a fuzzy completion / file selection helper. Its basic use is for selecting files from a large list (e.g., `find . -type f | fzf > selected`).

Once you install it and load it in your shell, you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to open a window in which you can type a fuzzy string to find directories. When you select one and press enter, fzf will `cd` to that directory.

To autocomplete filenames in the same way, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>. To seach history, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it isn't exactly what you want but I think it worth try [WCD](https://waterlan.home.xs4all.nl/#WCD_ANCHOR). It builds a "database" (a single textfile) which stores the list of directories. The `wcd foo` command show a list of the directories which contain `foo` and you can choose one of them.

Another similar option is [autojump](https://github.com/wting/autojump/).

Answer (score 0):

There are various shells and shell extensions that support [partial path autocomplete](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/94) and [fish](http://fishshell.com/) is one of them

For example `cd /v/l/fsck` <kbd>Tab</kbd> will convert the path to `/var/log/fsck/`. `cd /u/s/appl` <kbd>Tab</kbd> will expand the path to `/usr/share/applications/`

Some other alternatives:

- [fuzzy bash completion](https://github.com/mgalgs/fuzzy_bash_completion)
- [Command-T](https://github.com/wincent/command-t):

  [image: Command-T in action]

See also

- [Find file modes in console (fuzzy completion)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5154539/995714)
- [Command-T for shell](https://superuser.com/q/392496/241386)